# Objective-C how to convert a NSArray to Byte array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, byte, nsarray

I'm not very experienced with objective-c and I would need to advise for the following use case:

I'm coding a React native module for ios and one of the native methods on the ios side receives an `NSArray` containing integers (each integer has a value between 0 and 255).

In my objective-c code, I need to convert this `NSArray` to a `Byte bytes[]` to pass it then to some SDK I use.

How can I do that conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray* array = @[@(1), @(5), @(115), @(34)];

Byte* bytes = calloc(array.count, sizeof(Byte));

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber* number, NSUInteger index, BOOL* stop){

    bytes[index] = number.integerValue;
}];

doWhateverWithBytes(bytes);
free(bytes);
```

assuming that `doWhateverWithBytes` accepts `Byte bytes[]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! `sizeof(byte)` gives `Use of undeclared identifier 'byte'`

Comment: Shouldn't it be the size of array instead?

Comment: The size of the array comes as the first parameter to calloc